# Can this quote from The Fifth Estate be attributed to Julian Assange?

Tags: dialogue, the-fifth-estate

Did Julian Assange say or acknowledge being said the following dialogue in real life which appears on [**The Fifth Estate** script](https://wikileaks.org/The-Fifth-Estate.html).

```
  It takes two things to change the
  world. You'd be surprised how many
  people have ideas. But commitment,
  true commitment, that's the hard
  one. It requires sacrifice.
```

Comment: https://wikileaks.org/The-Fifth-Estate.html#3fiction I think that almost everything is a fiction in that movie and the quote was  something that the screenwriter made up but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Although it certainly matches the high-rhetoric in which Assange is so fond of writing, I've come to the conclusion that this line was an invention of the screenwriter, not least because Assange has spoken [extensively](http://www.support-julian-assange.com/category/julians-quotes/) about how one can ***change the world*** (in this case by understanding history and rejecting the conclusions) without ever mentioning "committment" and/or "sacrifice"

> We live in the world that we perceive. Our limits are the limits of
>   our perceptions. This generation knows more than any previous
>   generation. Its actions will eclipse those of previous generations. **We
>   change the world by observing its behavior, thinking about our
>   observations and acting on our thoughts. To observe we must open our
>   eyes. To think we must open our minds.** To act, we must open our
>   hearts. Our eyes have never been so wide. Our minds never so trained.
>   And the courage in our hearts spreads like a contagion.

There's also a brief mention in Assange's autobiography about a blog post on his old site about how "[true committment](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wkvsOtUQ47YC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22julian%20assange%22%20and%20%22true%20commitment%22&source=bl&ots=8ltz0IMayd&sig=xTirWBlIs6B87IMk_UhyN2zO9q8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN1oK4hp_JAhXEMhoKHTBbD44Q6AEIUDAI#v=onepage&q=%22julian%20assange%22%20and%20%22true%20commitment%22&f=false)" is demonstrated

> "when they break down your door with their jackboots".

Nothing to do with changing the world.

---

As far as I can tell, the quote is, at best, an amalgam of things he's said elsewhere and at worst a total fiction.